# Не срабатывает крон на выполнение скрипта php в заданное время.

Tags: php, битрикс, cron

Пробую запустить крон на выполнение скриптов раз в час `*/1 * * * /var/www/vhosts/supply-dev.evraz.com/httpdocs/supply-dev/test1/index.php`. Причину не могу найти почему не срабатывает. Помогите пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы передаете не все значения запуска крона.

**UPD** поправлено, для запуска раз в час в 00 минут.

```
0 * * * * /var/www/vhosts/supply-dev.evraz.com/httpdocs/supply-dev/test1/index.php
```

Comment: И будет срабатывать раз в час? если `*/1` заменить на `*`?

Comment: расшифровывается так: `минуты, часы, день, месяц, день недели`, если нужно раз в час, тогда делайте `0 * * * *`, соответственно сработает каждый час в 00 минут.

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую